# cancel a search in nano?

Tags: terminal, kill, nano

So I'm editing this 1MB file on a slow command-line only Debian machine, and I accidentally forgot to untick a "Search Backwards" mark when searching for something.  So now Debian is searching for that word-- except if I understand correctly, when searching backwards it has to re-read the file from the beginning, for each buffer that it searches backwards.  Let's just say that I ate dinner, and it's only gotten to the beginning of the file.  And searching in the end of a file takes longer than in the beginning.

Oh, and one other problem.  I don't remember when I saved the file last.

Few options that may or may not exist, but would solve this problem:

- Some command to cancel search in `nano`?
- Some Debian command to pause current process and go to the command line, so I could check how much of the file has been saved? (similar to CTRL+ALT+DEL)
- I have no network connectivity; but, Debian seems to have a daemon switching to the USB directory, when I insert a USB.  Maybe this can somehow be exploited to put an auto-run on the USB, that when inserted would copy the file in question to the USB?

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to cancel a search.

In applications that follow classical Unix key bindings, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> means “stop doing what you're doing and go back to the top level”. In a terminal, by default, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> sends the [SIGINT signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)#POSIX_signals) and this terminates the foreground process, but applications can override either the binding of the key to the signal or the action of the signal.

Nano captures the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> key press, and does something different when it's pressed at the toplevel, but it goes with the classical meaning while it's doing something potentially slow such as a search.

To pause the current terminal application and go back to the shell command line, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. This sends the SIGSTOP signal by default, which suspends the foreground process, and most terminal applications respect this meaning. In the shell, to resume the last suspended program, run `fg`. To see a list of suspended programs, run `jobs`. This is part of [job control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_control_(Unix)).

I assume you aren't running a window environment since otherwise you'd just switch to another window. If you're at the console on a PC, you can usually switch to another console by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, etc.

Comment: Ctrl+C was the first thing I tried.  :)  Haven't thought of CTRL+Z, but it didn't work.  Might it depend on the `nano` version?  I have another machine with the same setup, that I can use to pull parameters about anything...  Also: ALT+F* did not work either.  I guess Debian only starts a single console, to preserve its resources as much as possible.  Obviously not a window environment.

Comment: @Alex I tried Ctrl+C on nano 2.5.3 (Ubuntu 16.04) and it worked. Nano stopped the search and displayed `[ Cancelled ]` after a second or so.

Comment: So, probably it's a Debian thing then.  But yeah, I just went through CTRL+ everything on the keyboard; CTRL+Z apparently turns scroll lock off :D (which is turned on by CTRL+S).  But yeah, it appears that CTRL+Scroll Lock is the only interrupt to `nano`, and then I am not sure what it does.  It looks like it dumps some system-stats-looking commands to the command line, much too quickly for me to read, and goes back to `nano`.

Comment: Well, it now is finished.  Thanks for your help.  I'll keep the question open, in case this ever happens again and I'll need to figure something out.

Comment: @Alex Given the scroll lock effect you seem to have strange terminal or keyboard settings. Is this on a PC or some different hardware? What's your keyboard layout? Do you have `stty` commands in your config files?

Comment: It is running Debian, optimized to work as an embedded OS (so I guess that means it's not quite a PC).  I do have `stty` commands.  Standard keyboard layout, as far as I know (though this device has several extra keys: for example, one that moves forward a word in `nano`, without pressing any other buttons).